# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Command Line Tool setup

Tags: 12.04, command-line, amazon-ec2, aws

I have the AWS Elastic Beanstalk Command Line Tool running on my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Virtual Machine but I can only get it to work if i set the location of EB to the exact website folder I am going to deploy. I would have thought I could have put this somewhere generic and called it at whatever location i was in. This is how i am having to set it up at the moment:

> export PATH=$PATH:/home/lee/websites/my-specific-website-folder/aws-cli/eb/linux/python2.7/

Comment: The fact that you'd set PATH correctly means that you can call it from wherever you want without the path-to-script every time. You still have to use it from the root of your repository (same as git). Or did i miss something?

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to the directory that you want the eb command to be available in and then export the path. Every subdirectory will then have access to eb. In your case I think you should go to your home directory (cd ~/) and then run the same command. It should then be available to all of your website specific directories.